# Formatting ps output based on given parent/child processes

Tags: linux, ps, text-formatting

Given a list of process names, I want those parent/child processes to not appear in the output of a `ps --forest` call.

This will reduce the processes that I need to look at when I'm tracking things.

Comment: Hi, Jeff. Sorry if my wording was unclear. I want parent/child processes of processes that are NOT part of the list I provide. I'm trying to exclude parent/child processes of processes that I know I do not want to look at in my output.

Comment: What do you mean by "a list of process names"?  Do you mean a list of pids, or a list of commands?  What is a "process name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hard way to do it: a function that will use `pgrep` to return pids -- excluding (`-v`) the given process names -- followed by a `ps` call that asks for a forest listing of *only* the desired pids:

```
function psexclude {
  case $# in
  (0)
        printf "Usage: psexclude procname1 ...\n" >&2
        return 1
        ;;
  (*)
        str=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "$*")
        wanted=( $(pgrep -fv -- "$str") )
        ;;
  esac
  ps --forest -p "${wanted[@]}"
}
```

For a shell without array support, consider an alternative:

```
#!/bin/sh

function psexclude {
  case $# in
  (0)
        printf "Usage: psexclude procname1 ...\n" >&2
        return 1
        ;;
  (*)
        str=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "$*")
        set -- $(pgrep -fv -- "$str")
        ;;
  esac
  ps --forest -p "$@"
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what I needed! I just have one more request: how can this be made to work within a legacy, sh only environment?

Comment: @lukemk1, try the alternative I just added, and see!

Comment: thanks for this correction! It does function in pure sh now, but it is not excluding anything given to it. I have copied some test output to pastbin [here](https://pastebin.com/xeCWiFr6)

Comment: Looks to me like too much quoting-- drop the double quotes around the process names, since they're not needed.

Comment: I dropped the quotes but still seem to have the same issue. Here is a link [again](https://pastebin.com/PXh6eXth).

Comment: I think the problem may be that the process names aren't matching exactly, e.g. `/sbin/udevd` versus `/sbin/udevd  -d`.  Try adding `-f` to the pgrep to have it match against the full process name. I'll update the post to match.

Comment: @lukemk1 did the -f option finish the job?

Comment: yes sorry I wasn't able to get back to you sooner. This now works exactly as I was wanting! Thank you very much for all of your help, I appreciate it!